# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. php

Tags: php, .net, web-services, soap

I understand that this "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" has come up a lot but all of the answers I've looked at don't seem to be helping me out.

Here's my WSDL : https://app.20-20insights.com/testepos/servicetrx.svc?wsdl

I'm trying to call the the BeginTrx() function but I'm getting an error.

Any advice or help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Martin.

setting the TrxIdentifier object

```
$trxIdentifier = new TrxIdentifier;

$trxIdentifier->ClientId = 9372490002639296;
$trxIdentifier->DeviceId = "123";
$trxIdentifier->OpId = "123";
$trxIdentifier->PosDescription = "123";
$trxIdentifier->PosId = "123";
$trxIdentifier->PosTxnId = "123";
$trxIdentifier->SiteId = "12312";
$trxIdentifier->Token = "3";
$trxIdentifier->TrxdateTime = new DateTime;
```

Performing the call...

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,  array('trace'=>true,
'exceptions'=>true,
'classmap'=>array('TrxIdentifier'=>"TrxIdentifier", 'MemberInfo'=>"MemberInfo", 'Response'=>"Response", 'MemberDetail'=>"MemberDetail")));

$response = $client->BeginTrx($trxIdentifier );
```

Error :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
a:InternalServiceFaultObject reference not set to an instance of an object.Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at CatalystSpsTrx.Contracts.Service.ServiceTrx.BeginTrx(MemberInfo& mem, TrxIdentifier conTrx) in C:\Projects\2010\CatTrxServices\CatalystSpsTrx.Contracts\Service\ServiceTrx.cs:line 38
 at _dynamic_CatalystSpsTrx.Contracts.Service.ServiceTrx.BeginTrx(Object , Object[] )
 at Spring.Reflection.Dynamic.SafeMethod.Invoke(Object target, Object[] arguments)
 at Spring.Aop.Framework.DynamicMethodInvocation.InvokeJoinpoint()
 at Spring.Aop.Framework.Adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.Invoke(IMethodInvocation invocation)
 at Spring.Aop.Framework.Adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.Invoke(IMethodInvocation invocation)
 at CompositionAopProxy_d0e73463863e4ccd9c2db0a96530bd0d.BeginTrx(MemberInfo& mem, TrxIdentifier conTrx)
 at ServiceTrx.BeginTrx(MemberInfo& mem, TrxIdentifier conTrx)
 at SyncInvokeBeginTrx(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)System.NullReferenceException
```

Comment: That error is generated by the server, not PHP.  You will have to look at the server code or notify the API administrator of the service you are using.

Comment: Thanks, I've sent them an email and I'm currently waiting to hear back from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error occurs because your input structure is wrong. Your WSDL states that it has to be called in this way:

```
$response = $client->BeginTrx(array('trx' => $trxIdentifier));
```

Take a look at the WSDL, here is the root input definition for service `BeginTrx`:

```
<wsdl:message name="IServiceTrx_BeginTrx_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:BeginTrx"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

As you can see, the input is of type `BeginTrx`. If you follow the WSDL, you'll find that is defined as:

```
<xs:element name="BeginTrx">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="trx" nillable="true" type="tns:TrxIdentifier"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So there you can see that `BeginTrx` has a param name of `trx` and a value of type `TrxIdentifier`.

Following the WSDL again, `TrxIdentifier` is defined as:

```
<xs:complexType name="TrxIdentifier">
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ClientId" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DeviceId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    .................
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Hi, that's excellent. It accepted my request. It did give me another error which I'll have to look into:
The value '9372490002639296' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'
pardon my ignorance too though, where do you see in the WSDL that it has to be passed in using 'trx'?

Comment: `ClientId` is a 32 bit integer, you're passing a number which far exceeds the maximum of `2147483647`. If you need to pass that number, the service provider will have to change the data type to a string to avoid the 32bit limit. I explained where `trx` comes from, look at my second WSDL snippet.

Comment: You are a hero my good man!
Thanks very much for you help. This is much appreciated.
Best explaination of this error I've seen.

Comment: Glad to have helped. This error is almost always due to a wrong input structure when calling .NET web services.